# Is this a correct use of “duquel”?

Tags: subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs

Is this a correct translation of "This generation has the potential to make the foundation of what could possibly be the future of human existence in the cosmos"?

"Cette génération a le potentiel à faire la fondation duquel peut possiblement être le futur de l'existence des humains dans le cosmos"

I really just wanted to make sure of my use of “duquel”, but I think I should've just used “quel”.

Answer (score 1):

Ce qui, donne, concaténé:

> Cette génération a le potentiel de poser les fondations de ce que
>   pourrait être  le futur de l'existence humaine dans le cosmos.

C'est un peu lourd, en inversant le verbe de la seconde partie:

> Cette génération a le potentiel de poser les fondations de ce que
>   le futur de l'existence humaine dans le cosmos pourrait être.

Comment: Ah, merci. Mais, ce qui "Poser" signifie en anglais? Et as tu des conseils sur comment savoir si un phrase est trop lourd à dire? I hope I said that right

Comment: "poser" means "to set down". For the foundations in means to build them.

Answer (score 0):

- "had" is a preterit, which is a past tense.
- In French you say "avoir le potentiel **de** faire quelque chose"
- "faire" is very vague in French, you should avoid using it as a translation from "make". "faire" is closer to "do". Here, use "fabriquer" for example.
- "duquel" doesn't mean that. Here some examples of the correct usage: http://www.wordreference.com/fren/duquel. "Quel" is not correct either. "De ce qui/de ce que" is definitely what you need here.
- "could" is a conditional, translate it by "pourrait".
- I wonder if even the English phrase is correct here by using "possible". I think they mean "possibly" in which case your translation ("possiblement") is good.
- "l'existence" is feminine in French, so it is "de l'existence".
- "le cosmos" is singular.